# SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HF1 - Add multimedia dialog crashing CMS

Tags: cme

I've a strange issue that when I click to to open the 'Add multimedia' dialog window from my component window, the pop up causes the CME window to crash.   This is happening in both IE and Chrome.

This doesn't happen when I open up the 'Add component' dialog, only the 'Add multimedia'.

It's a very strange issue, I was wondering if anyone had come across this one and knew of a solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at Microsoft's KB article 175500 related to script timeout settings.  Try the fix provided on this page and see if it helps:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Comment: cheers brother man!